# Hiding a navigation bar with .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched and searched trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. I would like to hide the navigation bar completely at a certain screen width but I am getting absolutely nothing. JS fiddle and Code Pen can't find anything and safari isn't showing syntax errors. I have only been at this a month, here it is I appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>No clue what I am doing</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     
  </head>
  <body> 
 <nav class="navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>     
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">     
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>    
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav> 

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready() 
var width = function(checkWidth) {
if(window.width>768) {
$("nav .navbar-default").hide()
} else {
$("nav .navbar-default").show()
}
};
width;
```

Comment: Why are you including two (different) copies of jQuery in the same page?

Comment: you are selecting the 'nav' and in that element you are searching for 'navbar-default', But the nav itself has the class 'navbar-default'. Maybe thats why it don't work

Comment: One is a older version of jQuery. I actually didn't notice that I included it on the page. Will loading both pages cause errors or will it just slow the loading time down? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load the script on page load as well as on screen resize. This may help:

```
function toggleDiv(){

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {

            $("nav.navbar-default").hide();

    }else{

        $("nav.navbar-default").show();

    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleDiv();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        toggleDiv();
    });

});
```

OR you can just use media queries like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .navbar-default {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really good suggestion I have not tried this yet. I didn't even think about loading the page twice. Media queries seem like the best route to go. Do you enter these into your CSS? Also, is there anything that I have to do to make these work? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Answer updated with the `navbar-default` class in the queries and yes, you just copy this to your css file and you're good.

P.S. I would recommend you add `navbar` to your class to avoid missing some standard properties set by bootstrap like this: `<nav class="navbar navbar-default"><div class="container-fluid">....</div></nav>`

Comment: Awesome, it is working. Thank you I had tried about ten different methods until you sent me this. I didn't realize that you could just slap media queries into your stylesheet. I thought that you had to compile something to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: I hit the green arrow to accept the answer but I don't have enough reputation points to upvote it with the other one.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to hide a child with the class `.navbar-default` of your nav, when you are actually wanting to target the nav itself:

```
<nav class="navbar-default">
```

This is targeted as:

```
nav.navbar-default
```

not:

```
nav .navbar-default
```

That one space character is extremely important here.

Comment: Ok I will correct this and see what happens. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I have found two ways of finding the width of the user's screen in JS:

1. [screen.width](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp)
2. [window.innderWidth](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp)

I hope they may be of assistance to you.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will try both ways.